# Clear up elastic search data - disk space used is higher

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, virtual-machine, diskspace

I got this error in Kibana while loading my docs in discover option

> index [.async-search] blocked by: [TOO_MANY_REQUESTS/12/disk usage exceeded flood-stage watermark, index has read-only-allow-delete block];

To resolve this used these commmands to get back the write mode

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

So I have almost deleted all the index to free up space but still the disk space is full why ?
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v'

[image: curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v']

My disk.indices size is very less compared to disk.used , I wanted to know more details about the spaces usage and how to delete clear the existing disk space and delete the data ?

Kindly help me to resolve this ... :)

Comment: What do you get when running `GET _cat/indices?v&bytes=b&s=i:desc`? Also do you have anything else installed on this node or only ES and the system?

Comment: install ncdu on your server and check what is occupied the disk. and why you have unassigned shards?

Comment: I have installed ELK stack in same instance and when I tried  @Val your command it gives >>[3] 12887
[4] 12888 >> not sure what is it ?

Comment: Run it in Kibana Dev Tools or `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&bytes=b&s=i:desc'`